# How to add Custom User Interface to Sales Force

Tags: user-interface, salesforce, customization, visualforce

I'm trying to add a custom **User Interface** to *SalesForce* pages, how should I start?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes , I have tried using apex , but i need to develop custom user interface , like chatter plugin , and i also need to locate it at the bottom of sales force page

Comment: Look into using visual force pages and overriding default controllers.

Comment: you are talking about Standard Controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can customize your page UI with two simple steps:
1. Add attributes in your page element to remove default header, sidebar and stylesheets attached to the page.
2. Add CSS and jQuery if required from Static resources. This is optional step but very useful when work with large CSS and jQuery codes.

Adding attributes:

```
<apex:page id="thePage" controller="yourController" action="{!yourAction}" docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
```

Adding static resources:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.yourJS}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.yourCSS}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can develop fully custom user interface on Visualforce pages and controllers. First, you can removes standard components (tabs, header and footer) from page using such options in  tag:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
```

So, you will have clear page on which you can add your markup. Also you can develop templates pages,  which will include common application interface parts. Read more about Visualforce templates [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_templates_composition.htm).
Also you can use [Salesforce custom components](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_comp_cust.htm).

You can also use the popular CSS and JS frameworks. So it will be more development of front-end part and on server side you will just create actions methods in page controllers for UI.